# Как с помощью JS разложить данные из массива по нужным местам?

Tags: javascript, json

У меня задача, одним запросом получить данные по нескольким сообществам и количествам событий. Сообщения, комментарии и т.д.

Так вот есть страница, на которой приведен список сообществ для отслеживания, там есть иконки обозначающие виды событий Сообщения, Комментарии, Посты.

Получаю массив такого типа:

```
{"id73169318":{"message_new":"44","comment_new":"0"},"id23916815":{"message_new":"0","comment_new":"3"}}
```

Нужно JS скриптом например раз в 20 секунд делать такой запрос и раскладывать по нужным местам, например:

```
<div class="id73169318 message_new"></div>
<div class="id73169318 comment_new"></div>

<div class="id23916815 message_new"></div>
<div class="id23916815 comment_new"></div>
```

Как это можно сделать? Подскажите, а то получить получаю массив, а как пройтись по списку и разложить по нужным местам, не могу понять...

Comment: каждый раз вставка должна быть в тех же самых блоках?

Comment: Ну может быть как 2 сообщества так и 10,20,30

Comment: _Получаю массив такого типа:_ - это не массив. Используй [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) цикл по этому объекту и все

Comment: @Grundy человек только изучает, должны помочь, да это не массив, это `JSON` строка

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, это не строка :-)

Comment: @Grundy Перепутал объект)))))

Comment: @grundy да именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовать все это можно при помощи `ES2015`, Так будет проще, циклом проходим по объекту и по `key`-у выбираем нужный элемент и вставляем значение

```js
"use strict";


$(document).ready(function(){
    let obj = {"id73169318":{"message_new":"44","comment_new":"0"},"id23916815":{"message_new":"0","comment_new":"3"}};
  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    $(`.${key}.message_new`).text(obj[key]['message_new']);
    $(`.${key}.comment_new`).text(obj[key]['comment_new']);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>id73169318 message_new</label>
<div class="id73169318 message_new">x</div>
<label>id73169318 comment_new</label>
<div class="id73169318 comment_new"></div>

<label>id23916815 message_new</label>
<div class="id23916815 message_new"></div>
<label>id23916815 comment_new</label>
<div class="id23916815 comment_new"></div>
```

Подробнее об `EcmaScript 6` можете прочитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-modern-usage).

Comment: _Object.keys_ - это не ES2015, это ES5. Поэтому версию, в принципе, можно не указывать. По сути кроме template strings из ES6 ничего не использовано, но про них в описании ничего нет :)

Comment: @Grundy а там только это использовано? посмотрите здесь `$(`.${key}.message_new`)`.

Comment: @Grundy Тогда можно было начать перечислять с первой версии?)))

Comment: это и есть template string

Comment: @Grundy И? что хотите сказать?

Comment: все получилось! спасибо большое!

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Пожалуйста .